# Decimal issue (Oracle 11G)

Tags: oracle

I was debugging an issue on one of our Oracle databases with Pl/Sql developer and found this issue.

This is the select statement I ran on Pl/SQL:

```
SELECT  24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date),
t.plan_hrs,
24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date) - t.plan_hrs
FROM active_Separate t
WHERE t.wo_no = 613484;
```

This is the result I got:

```
-----------------------
a        b         c
-----------------------
.5       .5        8E-40
```

Just by looking at it, a = .5 and b = .5; therefore a-b (which is c) should be 0, but it's 8E-40.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Plan_hrs is of type NUMBER and both plan_f_date and plan_s_date are of type DATE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you have aliased your query as follows:

```
SELECT  24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date) as a,
        t.plan_hrs as b,
        24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date) - t.plan_hrs as c
FROM ...
```

I'm able to produce similar results with the following test data:

```
WITH testdata AS (
  select to_date('00:30','HH24:MI') as plan_f_date
        ,to_date('00:00','HH24:MI') as plan_s_date 
        ,0.5 AS plan_hrs
  from dual
)
SELECT  24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date) as a,
        t.plan_hrs as b,
        24*(t.plan_f_date - t.plan_s_date) - t.plan_hrs as c
FROM testdata t;

a: 0.4999999999999999999999999999999999999992
b: 0.5
c: -0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000008
```

These inexact results are because dates are accurate down to the second, subtraction of dates returns a number where 1 = 1 day, the smallest unit (1 second) is equal to approximately 0.00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407 of a day, so you're going to get small errors creeping in as soon as you do multiplication of the results.

Therefore you probably need to round the result to get 0 (zero).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, guess you are correct. Yes, I aliased them as you indicated.
It's just that while you got the value for 'a' as 0.4999999999999999999999999999999999999992, I got my value for 'a' as .5 - which caused the confusion when I saw my result set.
Many thanks again for your time and effort. Cheers.